# Submit form linked to ajax data result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

I have my input form that collects data. I want to check if one of this input is present in my mySql db and to do this I call the procedure via AJAX.

The procedure makes a mySql query and returns a value `"1"` or `"0"` if the record exists or not. All is ok with the AJAX request.

I can check if the data returned is `1` or `0`. The problem is that if the data is `0` (a record already exists) I have to avoid the submission form. But it doesn't work.

```html
<form id="frm" name="frm" action="000.php?us=1&usop=1&ada=1" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input name="elm" id="elm" type="text" style="width: 100%;" required>
  <input name="vin" id="vin" type="text" style="width: 100%; text-transform: uppercase;" required>
  <button class="btn-success" type="submit" id="go" name="btn-login">Go!</button>
</form>
```

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';
  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var forms = document.getElementsByClassName('needs-validation');
    var validation = Array.prototype.filter.call(forms, function(form) {
      form.addEventListener('submit', function(event) {
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
          event.preventDefault();
          event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
      }, false);
    });
  }, false);
})();

$(".btn-success").click(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      q: $('#elm').val(),
    },
    url: "getunique.php",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data === '0') {
        $("#elm").val("");
        alert("duplicated!");
        return false;
      } else if (data === '1') {
        document.getElementById("frm").submit();
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: `.btn-success` has type="submit" which will always submit the form unless you prevent the default action. Upon AJAX success, it's never told NOT to submit, so I think you need to `preventDefault()` instead of `return false` in your ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you should hook to the `submit` event of the `form` and call `preventDefault()` on the Event. You can then make your AJAX request to determine the state of data and then either manually resubmit the form, or do nothing if the submission should not be allowed.

Here's an example of what the logic would look like:

```js
$("#frm").on('submit', e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      q: $('#elm').val()
    },
    url: "getunique.php",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data === '0') {
        $("#elm").val("");
        alert("duplicated!");
      } else if (data === '1') {
        e.target.submit(); // resubmit form
      }
    }
  })
})
```

As an aside, you should review how your `getunique.php` is returning data. Returning a plain-text response is not good practice as it's very brittle, and will easily be broken. In addition, returning a string for a boolean output is not ideal.

I would suggest you instead return JSON with a boolean flag that you can then interrogate to determine the action to take.